# Where can I get windows.h for Mac?

Tags: c++, c, windows, macos, opengl

I'm trying to compile a program on MacOSX that I originally wrote on a Windows OS.  The program is a large C++ program with the OpenGL API among other things, totaling very many directories and files.

The compilation process at first had a problem with OpenGL for the Mac so I downloaded all the command line utilities of OpenGL for it to work.  But as you might imagine, each C file within the OpenGL download had many preprocessors, each of which I in turn had to downloaded the dependencies for.

However, I have remaining one critical step: I receive a fatal error saying that windows.h file is not found.  This seems something inherent to the Windows system (the windows.h file is nowhere to be found in my huge list of directories for the program), and the Mac does not seem to have an equivalent for windows.h (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/96087-windows-h-mac.html).

Am I out of luck trying to compile this program for the Mac or can something be salvaged?

Comment: I would suggest to install vmware fusion and windows inside it to compile your code with windows.h included. You can somehow include windows.h in mac but you will never be able to run the code as windhows.h as it specific to windows and contains OS specific calls and declarations linking to windows specific dlls and definitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing you can do is create a dummy file called `windows.h` to satisfy the `#include` directive, then track down the missing typedefs, #defines, etc. one-by-one by looking at the compiler error log.

`Windows.h` is monolithic and includes about a hundred other Windows headers, but your program is not going to need all of those definitions. This assumes you are not using the Windows API directly, and only using simple things like `DWORD`. If your software is built using a framework like GLUT or GLFW that is entirely possible, but if you directly interface with WGL, you are going to have a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: I'm interfacing with beGUI, would that be a problem?

Comment: @white_rabbit: There appears to be a little bit of Win32-specific code in the beGUI framework in `FrameWindow_win32.cpp/h`. I am not familiar enough with it to tell you if you have to re-write that to make it work on OS X, but there appears to be an example that uses GLUT *instead* of the Win32 API (`begui\src\begui_glut_example`) - that example should be portable.

Comment: It appears that the dummy file approach causes problems: OpenGL seems to use the win32 api: `../bcore/src/GL/wglew.h:114:15: error: unknown type name 'WINAPI'`

Comment: Do you think perhaps using GLFW (instead of beGUI) would help?  Or is the fact that OpenGL requires the Win32 API cause for only keeping this Windows-compatible?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't require Win32 at all. Each platform has its own API that handles windowing for OpenGL, the Windows API is called WGL. OS X uses three different APIs: AGL/CGL/NSOpenGL (it's a confusing mess). Now, from the error you posted it appears that beGUI depends on WGL. GLFW wouldn't have this problem, but it's not a GUI framework. Are you using beGUI to do anything GUI related, or just to create an OpenGL window?

Comment: Perhaps the trouble I'm having is making a dummy windows.h file then... what would I need to include within it to be a minimal working example kind of file.  Some other errors I get are: `/bcore/src/GL/wglew.h:114:61: error: unknown type name 'HDC'` and `/bcore/src/GL/wglew.h:114:70: error: unknown type name 'UINT'`  So if I don't have to worry about the Win32 API, how can I make sure that my dummy file has the requisite bare essentials?

Comment: No, I can tell you from experience that this is not something you're going to fix by substituting typedefs. This software needs things like `HDC` because it is built on top of WGL. You can easily define those things to be `uint32_t` and solve a missing type error, but the types are going to be used in WGL API calls like `wglMakeCurrent (...)` and there is no substitute for that. You would have to re-write code unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63739/discussion-between-white-rabbit-and-andon-m-coleman).

Comment: Posted a similar thread for a parallel issue I am experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621813/how-to-set-a-path-to-opengl-extensions-viewer-on-mac

Answer (score 4):

`windows.h` is provided by the Windows SDK, and implemented by the Windows OS itself.

You need to rewrite the program to not use Windows APIs.
Good luck.

Comment: Do you think the approach above of making a dummy file would work if I'm using a cross-platform interface such as beGUI?

Comment: @white_rabbit: Only if you aren't using any actual functions from windows.h.

Comment: Okay, so looks like OpenGL is using the win32 API: `../bcore/src/GL/wglew.h:114:15: error: unknown type name 'WINAPI'`  This is a significant problem, is it not?

Comment: I am considering rewriting from beGUI to GLFW?  Would you advise this to help this issue?

Comment: @white_rabbit: OpenGL does not use the Windows API. But you mentioned you downloaded a number of tools and files for OpenGL. Why did you do that? You don't have to do that. Most likely your problems are with this thing you did.

Comment: @datenwolf Because the mac would not recognize things like `#include  <glew.h>` which comes from OpenGL. I tried installing OpenGL for Mac, but could only find the OpenGL Extensions for download.  Why would my problems come from doing this?

Comment: @datenwolf I posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621813/how-to-set-a-path-to-opengl-extensions-viewer-on-mac to illustrate in this regard...

Comment: @white_rabbit: You can not and you should not "install" OpenGL for Mac. OpenGL is part of the standard system environment and on Macs actually embedded very deep in the system. GLEW is a 3rd party library and I recommend to copy it into your projects source tree and adding it to the list of files to be compiled and linked. However on MacOS-X **there is no use for GLEW, because MacOS-X's OpenGL doesn't expose a lot of extensions.** You can safely ignore it on MacOS X.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get Windows.h for mac, it is Windows OS specific.
There are many alternatives to functions used in Windows.h on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x86_64-w64-mingw32` to cross compile win32 programs on MacOS. It includes `windows.h`.

Comment: Would these programs run under MacOS, or would you need to copy the executables over to a Windows machine and run them there?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Won't run under MacOS. Would have to copy it to a Windows machine.

Comment: This is misleading; OP wants to compile on their Mac, *for* Mac. MinGW compiles for Windows and Windows only (which is the very point of MinGW). So even if MinGW can somehow be used to build the program on Mac, it'll only run on Windows and will therefore not achieve what OP needs.