# How to set a path to OpenGL Extensions Viewer on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I downloaded the [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opengl-extensions-viewer/id444052073?mt=12) for my Mac.  I am trying to compile a C++ program, which includes OpenGL dependencies such as `#include <glew.h>` within the source code.  To accomplish this, in Terminal I type:

```
g++ /some/path/to/folder/Application.cpp
```

But I get the error:

```
fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
```

Obviously this is because glew.h is not in the folder GL, it's somewhere within the OpenGL Extensions Viewer. But I am having considerable difficulties finding where the OpenGL Extensions Viewer downloaded to exactly, as it does not appear in my Downloads folder, and consequently I can't find the appropriate path to glew.h, which the Viewer should presumably have (according to the description on their website, it seems that the OpenGL Extensions Viewer should have every OpenGL file I would need to successfully compile my C++ program).

Comment: What makes you think that the OpenGL Extension Viewer contains GLEW? I don't think the two are related at all. GLEW does not really serve a purpose on Mac OS. It's for extension loading on Windows. I know it's supported on Mac OS, but I never understood why it would be useful. On Mac OS, you just include the OpenGL headers, and call the functions. No dynamic loading needed.

Comment: @RetoKoradi If OpenGL Extension Viewer does not contain GLEW, then what does?  The bottom  line is that I'm getting that error message and I'm trying to figure out a way to get the glew.h file, wglew.h file, etc., which I was hoping could be downloaded all together from one source for the Mac.  How can I obtain those requisite files on the Mac?

Comment: The official site seems to be here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/. I would still recommend to pass on GLEW, and simply include the OpenGL headers that come standard with Xcode.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Now I get: `/Users/Downloads/glew-1.11.0/include/GL/wglew.h:70:10: fatal error:'windows.h' file not found` I was hoping that the Extension Viewer would have this or some equivalent of this.  I asked about this yesterday at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600136/where-can-i-get-windows-h-for-mac  I would really appreciate any feedback you might have for this.

Comment: `wglew.h` definitely sounds like a Windows specific header that you don't want to include on Mac OS.

Comment: @RetoKoradi How can I work around this Windows specific header?  I posted a question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622338/how-can-i-change-an-opengl-source-code-file

Comment: @white_rabbit: Simply by not using GLEW. You don't need GLEW on MacOS-X.