# How can I change an OpenGL source code file?

Tags: windows, macos, opengl

I have an OpenGL file called wglew.h which I downloaded from http://glew.sourceforge.net/.  Using the wglew.h as I downloaded it, I receive the following error when compiling a program that I have (I am using MacOSX):

```
/Users/Downloads/glew-1.11.0/include/GL/wglew.h:70:10: fatal error:'windows.h' file not found
```

I am trying to go back into the source code of that file and change its dependency from windows.h to something that my Mac could recognize.  The source code snippet in the wglew.h file is:

```
#if !defined(WINAPI)
#  ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#    define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
#  endif
#include <windows.h>
#  undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
```

Is it possible to work around this windows.h dependency so that my program does not error out at this step?  I asked a similar, but not identical question about a parallel concept at: [Where can I get windows.h for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600136/where-can-i-get-windows-h-for-mac) Perhaps instead of looking for an equivalent windows.h file (if such exists for the Mac), I can try to devise a more subtle approach of changing the source code within the wglew.h file to get my program to work and accommodate the windows dependency that I am experiencing?

Comment: @genpfault The program I am trying to compile on the Mac uses OpenGL, and I made the GUI portion of the program in Windows.  OpenGL is native on Windows, so on the Mac I download the necessary OpenGL components from http://glew.sourceforge.net/  However, as you can see, there is a windows-dependency within the wglew.h file.

Comment: That's obviously the MS windows include file. You probably want to get the glew include files for OSX. Better yet, download the *whole* library, and follow the installation procedure, since you will most likely need the library to be able to generate a working executable.

Comment: @white_rabbit: OpenGL is native on MacOS X as well. In fact the whole graphics system of MacOS X uses OpenGL. The whole MacOS X user interface uses OpenGL. OpenGL is part of the very foundations of the MacOS X operating system. You don't have to install anything to get OpenGL on MacOS X. However because OpenGL is so deeply embedded in MacOS X this means, you need a full OS upgrade to upgrade the OpenGL version available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go again: **GLEW is not part of OpenGL**. It's a third party library.

**You don't need GLEW on MacOS X !**

*You're barking up the wrong tree!*

Instead of trying to fix GLEW (which you don't have to). Just fix your program to not use GLEW when being compiled for MacOS X.

Everywhere in your program where you find a

```
#include <glew.h>
```

or

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

*Change it* into

```
#ifndef __APPLE__
#include <GL/glew.h>
#else
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#endif/*__APPLE__*/
```

Put any occurance where a GLEW function is called between a

```
#ifndef __APPLE__
…
#endif/*__APPLE__*/
```

block as well.

**You don't need GLEW on MacOS X !** Don't use it there.

Comment: I now get a `fatal error: 'OpenGL/wgl.h' file not found` when I replace wglew.h with wgl.h.  Perhaps I'm replacing incorrectly?

Comment: @white_rabbit: Where for Bob's sake do you have written `wglew.h` anywhere in your code? Never, not even when compiling forWindows, use `wglew.h`. When using GLEW only use `glew.h` and nothing else. Look at my answer, you use `OpenGL/gl.h` (there's no **W** in it).

Comment: @white_rabbit: To make this clear, `wglew.h` and `wgl.h` are header files for accessing the Microsoft Windows specific helper APIs related to OpenGL (creating an OpenGL context and so on). As such including these headers makes code inherently locked to compiling for Windows. For cross plattform code you must not use those headers at all. I think this is part of your original problem, that you used *these* headers, instead of the portable headers.

Comment: I'm actually now thinking of using glut instead of glew to solve these issues (as the original GUI was developed on Windows OS, and hence the wglew issue).  What do you think?

Comment: By rewriting on glut, I won't be using wglew at all.  I will be doing the rewriting on windows and then porting it on the mac.  Do you have any advice for which best to use to accomplish this cross-compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719055/what-are-the-differences-between-glu-glew-glut-qt-sdl-opengl-and-webgl

Comment: @white_rabbit: GLUT and GLEW do completely different things. GLEW loads OpenGL extensions, i.e. on operating systems which expose only *old* OpenGL functions it gives you the new stuff; that's why you don't need it on MacOS-X, because that OS gives you the new stuff immediately (for varying degrees of "new"). – GLUT is a application framework, it opens windows, processes user input, implements a event loop. **You can not replace GLEW with GLUT**, *because they do different things.* How do you create the application window currently? Which libraries are you using on Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63961/discussion-between-white-rabbit-and-datenwolf).

Comment: Although On MacOSX you might have the function declarations ready, you still don't have things like `GLEW_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` to check whether an extension is supported _at runtime_. Also, if you develop on an old MacOSX version for something newer, you'll still have to use extension mechanism to get pointers to functions in the extensions released after that version of the OS. So your "You don't need GLEW no MacOS X!" is completely wrong in general.